# Will logstash insert duplicate documents when restarting after a crash

Tags: duplicates, logstash

In the scenario where Logstash crashes or the Elasticsearch server is not reachable, I might have to restart Logstash and begin processing a file that was half-way inserted into Elasticsearch.

Does Logstash remember which line in the log file was last processed and pick up where it left off, or will it insert duplicate documents?

I suspect that the `_id` could be a hash generated by the file and line number to avoid duplicates but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elastic products that read files (logstash, filebeat, or the older logstash-forwarder) remember where they are in the files that they're reading.

If the [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline.html) backs up, each component will then stop sending more logs until the congestion is removed.

There will be logs "stuck" in the pipeline.  IIRC, the logstash queue is 20 events.  If you kill logstash before it can write those, you'll lose those events.  They were working on making that better for logstash2, but it didn't make it in.

So, the risk is more of missing a few documents than getting duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there any docs on the "queue" algorithm you mentioned? I'm still unsure how it can know the document was already sent to elasticsearch if you restart logstash and it processes the same file again.